# [ESSR0007]S2Containerはnullあるいは空であってはいけません

Tags: java, linux, seaser2

SeasarのアプリをLinux環境で起動できません。

Tomcatのディレクトリは`webapps`のアプリが設定したんですが、下記のメッセージがでています。

```
[ESSR0007]S2Containerはnullあるいは空であってはいけません
```

Windowsの環境ではエラーがでませんが、Seasar2はLinux環境で起動する場合、何か特別な設定が必要ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 恐らく`app.dicon`ファイルがクラスパス配下に無いのが原因です。
   `WEB-INF/classes/app.dicon`
   にファイルが配置されているか確認してみてください。
2. クラスパス関連の設定値に、linuxでは使わないディレクトリ区切り文字`¥`(￥マークまたはバックスラッシュ）が入っていないか確認してみてください。

Comment: 上記チェックの確認をしましたが、同じのエラーが発生しています。恐らくapacheのワークディレクトリが悪い？